# Why are there two versions of Python 3 (3.9 and 3.10) on my MacOS Monterey system?

Tags: python

A few months ago, MacOS (currently 12.5.1) update installed the latest Python 3.10 on my system in, `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10`.

It seems it didn't remove the 3.9 though, since I also have `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9` (`3.9.13_3`) on my system.

I'm aware of good practices for Python versions management, I know I'm not the one who installed 3.9 since I use `pyenv` to manage my different Python versions, and I never the system Python for my projects.

Why MacOS has those two Python 3 versions?

Answer (score 2):

macOS did not install either of those python executables.

Those in /usr/local/Cellar are installed by Homebrew.

You have asked brew to either install them directly or they are required by another package you installed.